# Intel coffeelake-H UHD 630 GT2 driver fail to load (maybe not actually i915?)

Tags: intel-graphics, 21.04

Just got a new desktop. It has a single graphics adapter:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~88Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.1
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 "3D|VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [8086:3e9b]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:2212]
    Kernel modules: i91
```

If I boot with kernel args `i915.modeset=1` then there is no video output. If I boot with `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0` then I get video but there are functions of the display that don't work like viewing in portrait mode.

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

kernel modules running:

```
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    94208  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      28672  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               131072  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_intel        40960  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      32768  1 soundwire_intel
snd_hda_codec         147456  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
soundwire_bus          77824  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_core          294912  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_pcm               118784  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
kvm_intel             286720  0
btintel                28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             655360  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
kvm                   835584  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  9
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd                    94208  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_pch_thermal      20480  0
```

kernel commandline:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic i915.modeset=0 root=UUID=fac9e736-93df-4bf4-8527-b1380611f233 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

The driver is supposedly up to date for all Linux distros and it's supposedly i915 for the coffeelake chipset, but I'm suspicious that this is a newer version of the chipset and thus the driver is not up to date.

I uploaded my hw-probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=746808e2c5 and even that shows that the card is detected, but I don't or can't figure out how to get the drivers to take affect.

Comment: I thought it was resolved by now. You can try this setting. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=coffee-uhd-graphics&num=1 But this was back with 17.10. `i915.alpha_support `  See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642535/xorg-detects-no-displays-with-an-intel-uhd-630

Comment: Yeah, I wish it was. So far, nothing I've tried works. I'm still working on it. I've tried multiple distros with the newest kernels. I tried compiling a new kernel. Nothing I've tried so far works. So, I'll keep trying and whatever I find I'll post here.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the drivers were never the problem. I was using a DP -> HDMI adapter, which was the problem. I purchased a [different adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081GGNWCX) which solved my problem entirely.